# How to diagnose/fix Signature Digest Verification Failure on web service response?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-ws, ws-security, wss4j

I am using wss4jSecurityInterceptor for validation and securement actions on my webservice. The SOAP messages back and forth are secured with Signature, Encryption and Timestamp. The problem I am having is, the recipient is unable to verify my response signature and gets the following error:

> oracle.wsm.security.SecurityException: WSM-00061 : Signature digest verification failure. The system property xml.debug.verify should be enabled for the details about the digest calculations during verification phase (note xml.debug.verify slows down the signature verification for very large messages).

Here is the code that I am using to perform validation and securement actions:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(WebServiceConfig.class);
    @Bean
    public KeyStoreCallbackHandler securityCallbackHandler() {
        KeyStoreCallbackHandler callbackHandler = new KeyStoreCallbackHandler();
        callbackHandler.setPrivateKeyPassword("changeit");
        return callbackHandler;
    }
@Bean
public Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor() throws Exception {
    Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();
    // validate incoming request
    securityInterceptor.setValidationActions("Timestamp Signature Encrypt");
    securityInterceptor.setValidationSignatureCrypto(getCryptoFactoryBean().getObject());
    securityInterceptor.setValidationDecryptionCrypto(getCryptoFactoryBean().getObject());
    securityInterceptor.setValidationCallbackHandler(securityCallbackHandler());

    // encrypt the response
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementEncryptionUser("client_pub"); // alias of client public key
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementEncryptionParts("{Content}{}Body");

    securityInterceptor.setSecurementEncryptionKeyIdentifier("DirectReference");
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementEncryptionCrypto(getCryptoFactoryBean().getObject());

    // sign the response
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureAlgorithm(WSS4JConstants.RSA_SHA1);
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureDigestAlgorithm(WSS4JConstants.SHA1);
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureKeyIdentifier("DirectReference");
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementActions("Encrypt Signature Timestamp");
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementUsername("secret"); // alias of the private key
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementPassword("changeit");
    securityInterceptor.setSecurementSignatureCrypto(getCryptoFactoryBean().getObject());

    return securityInterceptor;
}
@Bean
public CryptoFactoryBean getCryptoFactoryBean() throws IOException {
    CryptoFactoryBean cryptoFactoryBean = new CryptoFactoryBean();
    cryptoFactoryBean.setKeyStorePassword("changeit");
    cryptoFactoryBean.setKeyStoreLocation(new ClassPathResource("cert/myKeystore.jks"));
    return cryptoFactoryBean;
}

@Override
    public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
        try {
            interceptors.add(securityInterceptor());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("could not initialize security interceptor");
        }
    }

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet> registerMessageDispatcherServlet(
        ApplicationContext context) {

    MessageDispatcherServlet messageDispatcherServlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
    messageDispatcherServlet.setApplicationContext(context);
    messageDispatcherServlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
    return new ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet>(messageDispatcherServlet, "/ws/*");
}
```

The receiving side suspects that the error is caused by the fact that the certificate sent as  has been corrupted by carriage return character sequence. Here is what it looks like:

```
  <wsse:BinarySecurityToken
    EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary"
    ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"
    wsu:Id="X509-124b3a03-73e3-4838-a254-f20883ff4184">MIIG1zCCBb+gAwIBAgIRAIVi4APh2tBtAAAAAFDvSXwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwgboxCzAJBgNV&#13;
    BAYTAlVTMRYwFAYDVQQKEw1FbnRydXN0LCBJbmMuMSgwJgYDVQQLEx9TZWUgd3d3LmVudHJ1c3Qu&#13; bmV0L2xlZ2FsLXRlcm1zMTkwNwYDVQQLEzAoYykgMjAxMiBFbnRydXN0LCBJbmMuIC0gZm9yIGF1&#13; dGhvcml6ZWQgdXNlIG9ubHkxLjAsBgNVBAMTJUVudHJ1c3QgQ2VydGlmaWNhdGlvbiBBdXRob3Jp&#13;
    dHkgLSBMMUswHhcNMTkwMzIyMTY1ODA5WhcNMjAwMzIyMTcyODA4WjCBgjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMx&#13; EzARBgNVBAgTCkNhbGlmb3JuaWExETAPBgNVBAcTCEJlcmtlbGV5MS4wLAYDVQQKEyVMYXdyZW5j&#13; ZSBCZXJrZWxleSBOYXRpb25hbCBMYWJvcmF0b3J5MRswGQYDVQQDExJtc2cudWNwLWl0LmxibC5n&#13;
    b3YwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQC9fSfO1cKz1D34dQaQF1ScY0eEGALm&#13; s3hkRRWMYPWTH8gZRpfP4iFLF9Sx09vagGFHUrru1xf8BnVyB2CsZnvHtE+bDrK4kp4hQpO8aXqf&#13; VEpn+SpY38aQDfZUqjRK6HJM5qxF/2xjNKSw41MPkXALK04yga07IwSUE+GpPt8i2noQPKKJufzf&#13;
    guA8Plmsnf9uNcpxFezNXC1k+HQBKeO0V+CZ4K5FKyckq64eT8VWbawF5CFoNigtbxTuHHClECV0&#13; VrzNNf5jj/cpymwOu51ljnPhGEY/f73DlEBZg8jpFcDSnAyYyJH2GFgz2wa0TiOpdxItTWHMXalb&#13; YtDH9VvRAgMBAAGjggMMMIIDCDAdBgNVHREEFjAUghJtc2cudWNwLWl0LmxibC5nb3YwggF/Bgor&#13;
    BgEEAdZ5AgQCBIIBbwSCAWsBaQB2AFWB1MIWkDYBSuoLm1c8U/DA5Dh4cCUIFy+jqh0HE9MMAAAB&#13; aaZyHvYAAAQDAEcwRQIhAJtC0LBFOfupRDy6BOvRrH6pAlvAJFFUWxMbbSRV59nOAiB/c2D5VOwS&#13; aBeC4czjDjUAAfeunN/npVLyX7i6v69aLgB3AId1v+dZfPiMQ5lfvfNu/1aNR1Y2/0q1YMG06v9e&#13;
    oIMPAAABaaZyHwQAAAQDAEgwRgIhAJj/g/g+UjWaoHCl7ldHG08zuUrL8XbAkR8Op4G+//nvAiEA&#13; sLoq29TrwnOtWa+O1+PRHCCllKD22yeKxdMUNrR2Pu0AdgCyHgXMi6LNiiBOh2b5K7mKJSBna9r6&#13; cOeySVMt74uQXgAAAWmmch7YAAAEAwBHMEUCIBVGxbR2c/ByOtfDRMlpIFPRYA5+dGkB4zJ7tjQ6&#13;
    moYYAiEAmFbeJdg9rCZt6qUqhRH2mxJlotRjp+mZmiHyRFmulykwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgWgMB0G&#13; A1UdJQQWMBQGCCsGAQUFBwMBBggrBgEFBQcDAjAzBgNVHR8ELDAqMCigJqAkhiJodHRwOi8vY3Js&#13; LmVudHJ1c3QubmV0L2xldmVsMWsuY3JsMEsGA1UdIAREMEIwNgYKYIZIAYb6bAoBBTAoMCYGCCsG&#13;
    AQUFBwIBFhpodHRwOi8vd3d3LmVudHJ1c3QubmV0L3JwYTAIBgZngQwBAgIwaAYIKwYBBQUHAQEE&#13; XDBaMCMGCCsGAQUFBzABhhdodHRwOi8vb2NzcC5lbnRydXN0Lm5ldDAzBggrBgEFBQcwAoYnaHR0&#13; cDovL2FpYS5lbnRydXN0Lm5ldC9sMWstY2hhaW4yNTYuY2VyMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFIKicHTdvFM/&#13;
    z3vU981/p2DGCky/MB0GA1UdDgQWBBRzakStBRG3O6NBdLt1XUkvwwKn4jAJBgNVHRMEAjAAMA0G&#13; CSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQAqt00w3oV4XgcdhcanJdgY/SUCtmN9I4jdras8vRson+wK6WJy6Em8&#13; EF5wyRDLOwUD75Rm9Ak23lKjYOcDTWQGG3YXrYh7xe3J8C+plEY1NAwNPXflCzxkDcdJ4pX0LDfj&#13;
    aC5FniAvKJ9ET7ZQvpCjBRd7wgOrkuhf3YjCFC3hM4E6D7cGb6DEhCh9nOy+e9woQ/C1LnDil3NX&#13; Vgqk3PMZYkUeHjxqItnDcOAeJaeqsAUiTxZbC8sQQ9ae/CPahghgSWEwL7tMrAH4nGT3yeBQl0I9&#13; O7H9xWj0ooQ8Wt6nO7pq64X5uc7W6iA3/1Of5uCntmMrsqPlvSscP6QVuPw6</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
```

My keystore is in PKCS format and I have also converted to jks. No dice. The certs in the keystore verify just fine with openssl command, so I know they are good.

I do my builds on a mac and deploy on CentOS. I have also copied the sources to CentOS and run the build there. Again, made no difference.

Has anyone run into this issue and solved it? Would appreciate any help!

Thanks much!

Comment: EDIT: The carriage return character sequence "&#13;" got omitted from the text of  my original post. Most likely got replaced by an actual carriage return!

Answer (score 1):

xmlsec library upgraded to 2.1.3.
wss4j-ws-security-dom upgraded to 2.2.3

Details: The problem was narrow and very obscure. I haven't put everything I did back to the way it was to see if the problem returns, but could do that easily. We use spring-ws-security and WSS4Jfrom apache to perform the validation and securement actions. Both libraries include xmlsec.jar which provides this functionality. In fact wss4j includes it twice since it also embeds opensaml , which in turn contains xmlsec. Spring-ws-security also contains its own xmlsec. They are all different versions. The problem with carriage returns is reported for xmlsec versions 2.1.0 and above.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SANTUARIO-482

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SANTUARIO-494

I updated wss4j to ver 2.2.3 (where this is ostensibly fixed) and also added the fixed version of xmlsec.jar directly for good measure.

Hope it helps someone else out. :-)